# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Error With Nested For Loop Components

Tags: reactjs

I have nested components generated through a for loop and was wondering how I can get rid of this error. I know I have to add a unique key, but I started to do that and got duplicate keys for children.

This is my code where I am rendering a bunch of nested array components through the map function. Here I am rendering the component families, then the components for each component family, then the courses for each of the components. Where do I have to add a key?

```
const renderCourseRequirements = (courseList) => {
    return (
      <Grid>
        {courseList.map((course) => {
          return (
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
              <Card sx={{ width: 200 }} variant="outlined">
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                    {course}
                  </Typography>
                  <Checkbox name={course}></Checkbox>
                </CardContent>
              </Card>
            </Grid>
          );
        })}
      </Grid>
    );
  };
  const renderComponents = (components) => {
    return (
      <Grid justify="center">
        {components.map((component, index) => {
          return (
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
              <Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined">
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography
                    className={classes.title}
                    color="textSecondary"
                    gutterBottom
                  >
                    {component.component_name}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
                    Required Number of Courses: {component.required_num_courses}
                  </Typography>
                  {renderCourseRequirements(component.course_list)}
                </CardContent>
              </Card>
            </Grid>
          );
        })}
      </Grid>
    );
  };

  const renderComponentFamilies = (componentFamilies) => {
    return (
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={4}
      >
        {componentFamilies.map((componentFamily, index) => {
          if (componentFamily.component_list.length > 1)
            return (
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                <Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined">
                  <CardContent>
                    <Typography
                      className={classes.title}
                      color="textSecondary"
                      gutterBottom
                    >
                      {componentFamily.component_family_name}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
                      Required Number of Components :{" "}
                      {componentFamily.required_num_components}
                    </Typography>
                    {renderComponents(componentFamily.component_list)}
                  </CardContent>
                </Card>
              </Grid>
            );
          return (
            <>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                {renderComponents(componentFamily.component_list)}
              </Grid>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </Grid>
    );
```

Comment: Add key to Grid tag and use the index as the key can solve this problem I thouught.
And make sure that your array's course does not have the same name(In your Checkbox tag)

Answer (score 0):

Add the key to the first `element` after the `return` inside your `.map` function.

like this:

```
<Grid>. 
        // pass in index but I would use a package like 'uuid' to generate unique keys for each grid if your dynamically doing rendering so react know what key to update in the dom.
        {courseList.map((course, index) => {
          return (
            // 'key' goes here inside '<Grid>'
            <Grid key={index} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
              <Card sx={{ width: 200 }} variant="outlined">
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                    {course}
                  </Typography>
                  <Checkbox name={course}></Checkbox>
                </CardContent>
              </Card>
            </Grid>
          );
        })}
      </Grid>
```

checkout React Docs: [React Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Dont use `uuid` either. Ideally have something form the api like a `course.id`

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response but I am still getting the error after adding Grid Key = {index} for all the loops

Comment: If the courseList is pulling data from an api check to see if it has an id you would pass that as the key its recommend if possible like @Richard Hpa said. if not you have to create you own method of generating these keys or using a library.

Comment: Is there anyway to check the tags within inspect element css? I'm still not sure why it doesn't work as I commented out the recursive rendering and just have the top -level and added index keys and it still generates that error

Comment: Where is this data coming from? and show us the updated code and `console.log()`  the `response data` you're storing your `courseList` Array into. As far as inspecting elements your browser should provide an option of dev tools to inspect elements.